# How to grab seperated integers from long string

Tags: php, string, integer

I am working on a enrollment system for a judo club. I am using a string to store the ID's of people, who showed up. It looks somthing like this:

0,3,4,7,8,10,

Now, I want to seperate each number into an integer array in PHP. What would the simplest solution to this be? :)

Comment: http://php.net/explode

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`explode()`](http://php.net/explode)

```
$ids = explode(',', '0,3,4,7,8,10');
```

Comment: What will this return? An array of integers?

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = '0,3,4,7,8,10';
$arr = explode(',',$str);
```

Answer (score 0):

use `EXPLODE`

```
$num = "0,3,4,7,8,10";
$pieces = explode(",", $num );
```

- [Explode Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)